# Trying to submit a form with $.post. It works but the callback function doesn't trigger

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form that I want to submit without redirecting the page. It mostly works, but I want to disable the submit button after it gets clicked.

```
<form name="confirm" id="confirm" method="post" action="confirm.php"
      style="margin:0; display:inline-block">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
           style="display: inline-block; width:unset;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="bttnSubmit" value="submit">Send Email</button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $form = $('form');
    $form.submit(function(){
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
            $("#bttnSubmit").removeClass('btn-primary')
                            .attr("disabled","disabled");
        },'json');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are disabling the button only after the post is completed . i.e you doing the disabling  in the response call back . By the time you reach that call back the post is over. Move the location of

```
$("#bttnSubmit").removeClass('btn-primary')
                            .attr("disabled","disabled");
```

outside of your response call back

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $form = $('form');
    $form.submit(function(){
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {

        },'json');

        $("#bttnSubmit").removeClass('btn-primary')
                            .attr("disabled","disabled");

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: That must be a common issue with using the callback function. Why does the spec allow one?

Comment: @zzxjoanw
Nothing wrong with the spec here. That call back is for doing things with whatever result you get back from the post request. You incorrectly used that call back to disable the button. Please note that the $.post call returns immediately with out blocking and continue to execute the remaining lines in the function body. The call back will be executed later when the response is back.

Answer (score 0):

has you try with event.preventDefault() before $.post ?

Comment: I could, but I want to have some visual indication that the button's disabled.